# Rails routing URL folders for product categories on show actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I'm trying to formulate some better urls for a "product" model I have, only on the show action.  I'm currently using friend_id to generate pretty slugs, which is fine, but I'm trying to improve the URL flow if I can.

Current my paths work like this

```
    example.com/products/pretty-url-slug
```

When saving a parictular product (to the Product Model), I also save a type_of attribute.  Which could be android, iphone, windows

So I am trying to ultimately have robust URLS like this

```
    example.com/products/iphone/pretty-url-slug
```

The problem is, that I don't have or believe I want an actual "iphone", "android", etc controller.   But I'd rather just update a combination of the routes and show action to handle this properly.

So far I've attempted to solve this by using a catch all on the routes, but is not working correctly.  Any suggestions or different ways to handle this elegantly?

```
           routes

           resources :products

           # at the bottom of my routes a catch all
           match '*products' => 'products#show'

           # match routes for later time to do something with to act like a  
           # normal category page. 
           match 'products/iphone' => 'products#iphone_index'
           match 'products/android' => 'products#android_index'
           match 'products/windows' => 'products#windows_index'

           show action in the products controller

               def show
                # try to locate the product
                 if params[:product].present?
                  slug_to_lookup = params[:product].split("/").last
                  type_of  = params[:product].split("/").second
                  @product = Product.find_by_slug(slug_to_lookup)
                else
                  @product = Product.find_by_slug(params[:id])
                end


               # redirect if url is not the slug value
               if @product.blank?
                redirect_to dashboard_path
              elsif request.path != product_path(@product)
                redirect_to product_path(@product)
              end
             end
```

This way to handle the problem sort of works, but I can't fiqure out how to append the type_of attribute and generate a valid URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion.   I was actually able to solve this and pretty simple when I thought it over.  This might be helpful for others.

In my routes I just created a route for every type of category I have. so every time a new category, I would need to add an additional route, example:

```
    # match for each product category
    match 'shop/iphone/:slug' => 'products#show', :as => :product_iphone
    match 'shop/android/:slug' => 'products#show', :as => :product_android
    match 'shop/windows/:slug' => 'products#show', :as => :product_windows
```

Then in the show action for products instead of directing, you would just render the products/show if the slug matches an existing product

```
   @product = Product.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
```

Then in your views, you could link to a particular category like this

```
   link_to "product", product_android_path(@product)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about defining your routes like this:

### **get ':controller/:action/:id/:user_id'**

Here, Anything other than :controller or :action will be available to the action as part of params.